# postgres tsheadline долго выводит

Tags: c++, sql, qt, postgresql

В моей таблице 3 колонки: ID, FileName, TextOfFile. Хочу настроить полнотекстовый поиск и чтобы вывод подсвечивался, использую tsheadline и такой запрос:

```
SELECT ts_headline('russian_hunspell', "TextOfFile", to_tsquery('russian_hunspell','Книга'), 'StartSel =<b> , StopSel = </b>, 
MaxWords=5, MinWords=3, ShortWord=5, HighlightAll=FALSE, MaxFragments=1, FragmentDelimiter = " ... " ') as ttt 
FROM "Table" 
Where "ID" = 2
```

В моей таблице 2 строчки. В TextOfFile первой строчки
текст размером меньше 2 кб, во второй строчке размер текста 12 мб.
Есть также вектор gin на TextOfFile. Explain (analyze) выводит информацию, что при запросе используется Seq scan (выполнение 24 сек), если его отключить, то будет использоваться Index scan (22 сек c использованием индекса встроенного в ID - так как он primary key).

Хотелось бы добиться времени выполнения 1-2 сек. Подскажите как можно оптимизировать запрос?
Или же как можно изменить tsheadline, чтобы быстрее работало?

Comment: подсветка совпадений в конкретных документах скорей всего в любом случае полный просмотр текста будет вызывать... индексы тут не помогут... документы такого объёма или дробить нужно или применять какие-то другие технологии поиска окромя встроенного в postgres... хотя 24 секунды всё равно подозрительно много...

Comment: Проверьте что именно занимает время. Уберите вызов ts_headline - как изменилось? Уберите вызов to_tsquery - что получилось? Предположу что время почти всё тратится на to_tsquery - материализуйте его в отдельную колонку (generated column если postgresql 12 или выше, триггер если более старые). seqscan или indexscan - для таблицы из всего 2 строк не имеет значения.